# MySQL INSERT or UPDATE if existing

Tags: mysql

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `list_advertLeaders` (
  `key` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  `points` int(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`)
)
```

So I want to `UPDATE` row or create it if not exists with:

```
INSERT INTO list_advertLeaders (name, points) VALUES ('John', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points=points+1
```

Executing it first time gives
John,1

Executing it second time is expected to give
John,2

yet it puts same values with new key
John,1
John,2

How to make it proper way?

Comment: Someone just -1, yet provided no comments.

Comment: that often happens :(

Comment: Since you apparently don't want duplicates in `name`, is there any point keeping `key` as the primary key?

Comment: adding a unique index on `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `name` field is not a primary key or marked unique, so duplicates are permitted. Alter your table to mark 'name' as unique like this

```
ALTER  TABLE `list_advertLeaders` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `name_UNIQUE` (`name` ASC);
```

Comment: Missed a keyword. Fixed.

Comment: For a new table it should go like `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS list_advertLeaders (
  'name' varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  'points' int(9) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY 'name' ('name')
)`

Answer (score 0):

As `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` suggests, it will only work if the `INSERT` statement violates a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint.

Since `name` shouldn't have duplicates, and if you have no other specific use for `key`, you could just define `name` to be the primary key of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `list_advertLeaders` (
  `name` varchar(18) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `points` int(9) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For such task i used to do:

```
INSERT INTO list_advertLeaders (name, points) select 'John', '0' from 
       ( select 1 as a ) a 
       where (select 1 from list_advertLeaders b where b.name='John') is null;

UPDATE list_advertLeaders set points=points+1 where name='John';
```

First will insert only if no record, otherwise it do nothing. I do it when have index on name and when such construction is fast(if you care about  - need compare with other including trigger on key in benchmark, thats vary depend of mysql version).